# How to access the individual elements of a deserialized Json object in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization

I am writing a program to access the currency data from the http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=INR. I am able to get the json data, desreialize it and move it to a var obj.

```
var obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

Now I want to access all the rates in obj, i.e the currency code and the currency value in separate fields and update SQL. I am not sure how to  use foreach or for loop on obj.

I tried using the following code but it gives error in the 2nd foreach loop.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> currency in obj)
{
    if (currency.Key == "rates")
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, double> i in currency.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", currency.Key, currency.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second foreach.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> currency in obj)
{
    if (currency.Key == "rates")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", currency.Key, currency.Value);
    }
}
```

You have already found the currency you want.

Comment: The first for loop only give me

Comment: In this case it returns rates : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String.System.Object]. There are 31 currencies which I need to access.